# Python task Substrings without loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

You have to count how many substrings of a given string starts and ends with the same letter.
**You cannot use in your code the following:** for,while,sum,map,reduce,filter,import,eval,exec,complile,single

My code but doesn't work properly:

```
def substringsV2(i,string,sub_list):
    if i == len(string)-1:
        return len(sub_list),sub_list
        # return len(sub_list)
    if string[:i + 2][0] == string[:i + 2][-1] and  string[:i + 2]not in sub_list:
        substring = string[:i + 2]
        sub_list.append(substring)
    if string[i:][0] == string[i:][-1]  and  string[i:] not in sub_list:
        substring = string[i:]
        sub_list.append(substring)
    return substringsV2(i + 1,string,sub_list)
 
def substrings(i,string,subs_list):
    if i == len(string):
        print(subs_list)
        return substringsV2(0,string,subs_list)
    if len(string[i]) == 1:
        subs_list.append(string[i])
    return substrings(i+1,string,subs_list)

s = 'aba'
if len(s) == 0:
    print()
else:
    print(substrings(0,s,[]))
```

For example input 'aba'
Substrings: **a, b**, **a**, ab, ba, **aba** ,

Output 4 , because there are 4 substrings that starts and ends the same letter

Comment: What does your code print?  What should it print?  What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I'm added the image in descriptions

Comment: Please don't add an image.  Can you add (as text) into the question what output you expect from the input of `babab`?  Can you also add what output your code is giving?

Comment: done @RocketHazmat

Comment: With the input of `aba`, your code correctly returns `4`.  What did your code return with the original input you were trying - `babab`?  That should return `9`, yes?  What did your code give?

Comment: @RocketHazmat with "babab" my code returns 7 , but it should be 10.

Comment: I'm getting: `b a b a b babab bab bab aba`, isn't that 9?  What's the 10th one?

Comment: @RocketHazmat b
a
b
a
b
bab
bab
aba
bab
babab

Comment: How do you get 3 `bab`?  I see the first 3 characters and the last 3 characters?  Where's the third one?

Comment: @RocketHazmat mb the latest one and 2 letters left